# regex: match pattern only if not preceded by special character / inside comment

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I have input like the following example(s) and need to only replace all `\input{.*}` commands, that are **not** preceded by a `%` somewhere on the line.

The input is LaTeX code, where `%` is starting a comment. That means that everything after `%` on the current line should not be interpreted as actual code and is actually just a comment. (even if it looks like code)

Example input:

```
this is \input{REAL.tex} real content    % \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo \input{REAL.tex} bar
\input{REAL.tex}
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
\input{REAL.tex} % comment
```

My current code:

```
$r = "/^(?P<prefix>(?!.*%).*)\\\\input[{\s]+(?P<filename>.*?)[\s}](?P<suffix>.*)$/m";
$data = preg_replace($r, "REPLACED", $data);
echo $data . PHP_EOL;
```

**CURRENT** example output:

```
this is \input{REAL.tex} real content    % \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo REPLACED bar
REPLACED
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
\input{REAL.tex}                         % comment
```

**EXPECTED** example output:

```
this is REPLACED real content            % \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo REPLACED bar
REPLACED
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
REPLACED                                 % comment
```

**Problem:** Unfortunately, my regex ignores the `\inputs` in the first and last lines completely due to the `%` comment in the middle, due to the lookahead assertion `(?!.*%)`.

**Question:** Do you see a way to achieve the desired output via regular expressions? The `\input{REAL.tex}` on the first and last line should be replaced as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that i don't need to use lookaround here it all!

Code:

```
$r = "/^(?P<prefix>[^%]*?)\\\\input\\{(?P<filename>[^}]*)\\}(?P<suffix>.*)$/m";
$data = preg_replace($r, "\\1REPLACED\\3", $data);
echo $data . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
this is REPLACED real content % just a \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo REPLACED bar
REPLACED
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
REPLACED % comment
```

Comment: Don't forget the odd case where `%` is escaped ie `\% just a \input{REAL.tex}` :)

Comment: @gwillie oh yeah, right! thanks a lot, that probably saved me another bug report.

Answer (score 2):

You need a lookbehind that checks if there was a `%` before:

```
/(?<=%).*?\\\\input\{.+?\}/mis
```

Lookbehind syntax is `(?<=(your regex))` for a negative lookbehind it is `(?<!(your regex))`

Integrated in your code this would look like

```
$data = 'this is \input{REAL.tex} real content % just a \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo \input{REAL.tex} bar
\input{REAL.tex}
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
\input{REAL.tex} % comment';

$r = "/(?<!%)([^%]*)\\\\input\{.+?\}/";
$data = preg_replace($r, '$1REPLACED', $data);

echo $newData . PHP_EOL;
```

Output is

```
this is REPLACED real content % just a \input{COMMENT.tex}
foo \input{REAL.tex} bar
REPLACED
%\input{COMMENT.tex}
REPLACED % comment
```

Comment: thx for your comment, but as you can see the command must not be directly preceded by `%` - there can be arbitrary other content in between. look at the example in the first line. Please note that lookbehind does NOT support quantifiers in PHPs PCRE implementation, so something like `(?<!.*%)` is not possible - but would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Corrected the regex in my answer above to `/(?<=%).*?\\\\input\{.+?\}/mis`

Comment: this is not working. can you please show how you would integrate that in my example? Note that prefix and suffix must be handled, too.

Comment: the output is the wrong way round, please take a closer look at the question and/or my own answer

Comment: Then show me an example how the output `Example input` should be exactly.

Comment: you can find the example out in my own answer to this question

Comment: Okay changed my regex and preg_replace call in the code in my answer again. Please check it.

Comment: now you essentially have the same regex as my answer, but without suffix and prefix. you can delete your lookaround assertion, as it has no effect. thanks for your effort.

Comment: oh, and the second test case still fails. i already have a working solution. thanks!

Comment: But your regex in you answer is wrong too: `foo REPLACED foo` should be `foo REPLACED bar` shouldn't it?

Comment: oh yeah, that was a copy paste error .. i replaced the second "foo" with "bar" for clearness in the input example in my question, but forgot to update my test file. it's doing well and fixed the bug. thanks for you sharp eyes ;)